# PAM Google Authenticator With SFTP And Other Apps

Tags: pam, two-factor, google-authenticator

I'm attempting to set up a situation where SSH Authorized Key + Google Authenticator Code is sufficient to ssh into the server.

This is working fine for normal SSH terminal operations - I'm prompted for a verification code, which I can enter, and be granted access.

However, when attempting to use SFTP from a dedicated client (Cyberduck, etc) or any other application that may access via SFTP (Coda) I'm unable to log in.

I do see a password prompt from these applications, but it does not seem to want to pass through the credentials to another authentication module.

Is there any way to configure the google authenticator module to accept credentials that have been passed through another module?  I'm guessing use_last_pass, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I know some other applications are beginning to have better 2-factor support (FileZilla), but I need to support a somewhat broader userbase.

Thanks for any advice!